# Get the next values I'm going to need on background threads before I need them

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm hoping to find some advice on the best way to achieve fetching a bunch of id values (like a database Identity values) before I need them. I have a number of classes that require a unique id (int) and what I'd like to do is fetch the next available id (per class, per server) and have it cached locally ready. When an id is taken I want to get the next one ready etc.

I've produced some code to demonstrate what I am trying to do. The code is terrible (it should contain locks etc.) but I think it gets the point across. Losing the odd id is not a problem - a duplicate id is (a problem). I'm happy with the guts of GetNextIdAsync - it calls a proc

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC EntityNextIdentityValue @Key", 
            new SqlParameter("Key", key))).First();
```

on SQL Server that uses sp_getapplock to ensure each return value is unique (and incremental).

```
static class ClassId
{
    static private Dictionary<string, int> _ids = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    static private Dictionary<string, Thread> _threads = new Dictionary<string,Thread>();

    static ClassId()
    {
        //get the first NextId for all known classes
        StartGetNextId("Class1");
        StartGetNextId("Class2");
        StartGetNextId("Class3");
    }

    static public int NextId(string key)
    {
        //wait for a current call for nextId to finish
        while (_threads.ContainsKey(key)) { }
        //get the current nextId
        int nextId = _ids[key];
        //start the call for the next nextId
        StartGetNextId(key);
        //return the current nextId
        return nextId;
    }

    static private void StartGetNextId(string key)
    {
        _threads.Add(key, new Thread(() => GetNextIdAsync(key)));
        _threads[key].Start();
    }

    static private void GetNextIdAsync(string key)
    {
        //call the long running task to get the next available value
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (_ids.ContainsKey(key)) _ids[key] += 1;
        else _ids.Add(key, 1);
        _threads.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

My question is - what is the best way to always have the next value I'm going to need before I need it? How should the class be arranged and where should the locks be? E.g. lock inside GetNextIdAsync() add the new thread but don't start it and change StartGetNextId() to call .Start()?

Comment: Is there a reason to get values in background thread?

Comment: Plus, what is the reason behind generating the ids before you need them? Why not generate exactly when you need them?

Comment: I'd like to get them up front for performance - do the database call for the next id before it's required rather than wait at the time I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your database generate the identity values, by marking that column appropriately.  You can retrieve that value with [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or similar.

The main failings of your implementation are the busy wait in NextId and accessing the Dictionary simultaneously from multiple threads.  The simplest solution would be to use a BlockingCollection like ohadsc suggests below.  You'll need to anticipate the case where your database goes down and you can't get more id's - you don't want to deadlock your application.  So you would want to use the Take() overload that accepts a ConcellationToken, which you would notify in the event that accessing the database fails.

Comment: Note that if you need an ID before the item exists, just create the item(s) and don't populate the data right away.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I'm happy with the function GetNextIdAsync - my questions are around threading/thread safety etc.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good application for a producer-consumer pattern.

I'm thinking something like:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _ids;
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Thread> _threads;
private Task _producer;
private Task _consumer;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

private void StartProducer()
{
    _producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
       while (_cancellation.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
       {
           _ids.Add(GetNextKeyValuePair());
       }
   )
}

private void StartConsumer()
{
    _consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
       while (_cancellation.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
       {
           UseNextId(id);
           _ids.Remove(id);
       }
   )
}
```

A few things to point out...

Firstly, and you probably know this already, it's very important to use thread-safe collections like `ConcurrentDictionary` or `BlockingCollection` instead of plain `Dictonary` or `List`.  If you don't do this, bad things will happen, people will die and babies will cry.

Second, you might need something a little less hamfisted than the basic `CancellationTokenSource`, that's just what I'm used to from my service programming.  The point is to have some way to cancel these things so you can shut them down gracefully.

Thirdly, consider throwing `sleep`s in there to keep it from pounding the processor too hard.

The particulars of this will vary based on how fast you can generate these things as opposed to how fast you can consume them.  My code gives absolutely no guarantee that you will have the ID you want before the consumer asks for it, if the consumer is running at a much higher speed than the producer.  However, this is a decent, albeit basic way to organize preparing of this sort of data concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the thread safe collections, the babies are safe for another day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `BlockingCollection` for this. Basically you'll have a thread pumping new IDs into a buffer:

```
BlockingCollection<int> _queue = new BlockingCollection<int>(BufferSize);

void Init()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(PopulateIdBuffer, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void PopulateIdBuffer()
{
    int id = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Simulate long retrieval
        _queue.Add(id++);
    }
}

void SomeMethodThatNeedsId()
{
    var nextId = _queue.Take();
    ....
}
```